# What operating range is the ponderomotive approximation valid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plasma-physics

Recalling the equation on the ponderomotive force experienced by a particle in a non-uniform oscillating electric field:

$$
F = \frac{q^{2}}{4 \ m \ \omega^{2}} \nabla E^{2}
$$

Could anyone shed light on what frequency range  the approximation applies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally assume the force is varying temporally fast, but spatially slow such that you can define a particle's position as a function of time as:
$$
x(t) = x_{o}(t) + \delta x(t)
$$ 
where the $x_{o}$ term is slowly varying term and the $\delta x$ term is for the quickly varying temporal term.  From this we also assume that $\lvert \delta x \rvert$ $\ll$ $\lvert x_{o} \rvert$ and $\lvert \delta \ddot{x} \rvert$ $\gg$ $\lvert \ddot{x}_{o} \rvert$ (where $\ddot{x}$ = $\tfrac{d^{2} x}{dt^{2}}$), i.e., the $\delta x$ changes are small spatially but the acceleration is large.  Another way to say this is that the following should be satisfied:
$$
k \lvert \delta x \rvert \ll 1
$$
which is basically saying the wavelength should be large compared to the spatial oscillation scale length.

As for the frequency, the ponderomotive effect is often invoked for Langmuir waves, which have rest frame frequencies, $\omega_{o}$, near the local electron plasma frequency, $\omega_{pe}$.  That is, the effect is valid for $\omega_{o}$ ~ $\omega_{pe}$.  If the rest frame frequency were down near the proton cyclotron frequency, $\Omega_{cp}$, however, and one wanted to examine ponderomotive effects on electrons the effect would not matter.  This is because the time varying fields are slower than the transit time of the electrons, which would violate the *fast time* variation assumption discussed above.

You can think of it in terms of potentials, where the ponderomotive potential goes as $\phi$ $\propto$ $\langle \delta v^{2} \rangle$, where $\delta v$ is the fluctuation velocity of the particles in the potential and $\langle \rangle$ is a spatial ensemble average.

Note that the lower frequency bound is not some set value but rather a relative term.  The proton plasma frequency ($\omega_{pp}$), for instance, is still fast enough for ponderomotive effects to matter on electrons.  In the case of three-wave decay of Langmuir waves, one of the daughter waves is an electrostatic ion acoustic wave which oscillates nearly at $\omega_{pp}$.  Note that $\omega_{pe}$ ~ 43 $\omega_{pp}$, but even so the ponderomotive force still matters.

Comment: By slow varying term I assume you at erfeering to a static field superimposed onto the alternating field, correct? More over, how would the ponderomotive approximation apply in an ionic liquid? My specific case involves an ionic liquid being subject to a ponderomotive electric field with ion densities of order ~10^21 per cc...but this gives me a plasma frequency in the infrared range...but it says that an RF supply could be used?

Comment: The RF frequency is of the order 1-100kHz, and the produced field will cause the ions to displace according to their specific mass at spatial scales much larger than their natural oscillation. But the ion density gives a 100THz plasma frequency. Shouldn’t this result in a net zero motion of the ions? It’s part of an electrophoresis problem I’m trying to understand, but the contradiction is that the plasma frequency is significantly higher than the oscillating field supply, but nonetheless the ions experience a “net motion.” in the order of centimeters. It’s somewhat similar to AC electrolysis.

Comment: I am guessing the presence of neutral particles modifies things.  What's the typical transit time of the ion through a single wavelength of the RF driving fluctuations?  The simple scenario laid out in my answer is not general, it's an approximation for a simple setup.  I used the lower cutoff for the importance in my answer because something like Alfvenic waves in the solar wind have wavelengths ~100 of km or more and rest frame frequencies ~0.05 Hz while electron thermal speeds are ~2000 km/s, i.e., electrons see the spatial variation faster than the temporal.

Comment: It wouldn’t be as simple as an ion oscillation in a plasma, because in this case there is a viscous force that acts to impede the ions motion proportional to the ions speed, and added thhe fact that in a liquid the positive and negative ions are in very close proximity due to having solid densities, so much of the effects like Plasma Langmuir Oscillations would not apply. But in terms of transit time, the RF wavelength is in the order of kilometers even as you say, and the ion speed is at 1-10mm/s, so you have incredibly high transit times in the order of 10^5-10^6s.

Comment: To be specific, by ion speed I am referring to the velocity of the ion when subject to an equivalent DC field assuming steady-state motion.

Comment: @Joeseph123 - If it takes ions >$10^{5}$ seconds to cross one wavelength but the period of oscillation is seconds or less, then the fast temporal, slow spatial variation assumptions hold.  The problem with your system is that it's more like a damped, driven harmonic oscillator than just a driven harmonic oscillator.  This will change things a bit but my best suggestion would be to look at papers on the poderomotive effect in lab or ionospheric plasmas where charge-neutral collisions are high.